# Finding the CDF

Tags: probability, self-study

I've been trying to understand this question I have below and I've been using [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243219/how-can-i-find-the-cdf-of-a-piece-wise-continuous-random-variable) as a reference.

The question:

I'm given a random variable

$X(\omega)=\begin{cases}
\omega, \quad 0\leq\omega\leq \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3}, \quad \frac{1}{3}<\omega\leq 1
\end{cases}$

I'm looking for its CDF and the probability measure is defined as $P([a,b])=b-a$.

The above example (linked post) is very helpful as it illustrates it using a uniform distribution, but I suppose I'm a bit confused on the part of $X(\omega)=\frac{1}{3}$ when $\frac{1}{3}<\omega \leq 1$.

So far my CDF looks like:
$P(X\leq x)=x\mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{3}]}$ but I'm not sure how to the CDF works from $(\frac{1}{3},1]$.

Comment: You're right about $F_X(x) = x,$ for $0<x<1/3.$ Also, $F_X(x) = 0,$ for $x <  0$ and $F_X(x) = 1,$ for $x > 1.$ Next, $P(X=1/3) = 2/3,$ so the CDF jumps from $1/3$ to $1$ at $x = 1/3.$ // Remember that a CDF is nondecreasing. What is its value at $x = .5?$// From 0 to 1/3, X acts like a continuous RV, then it acts like a discrete RV with probability 2/3 at 1/3. The CDF of a  strictly continuous RV has no jumps. // The CDF of the discrete  random variable $Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 2, p = 1/2)$ has jumps at 0, 1, and 2 of sizes 1/4, 1/2, 1/4, respectively; a 'pure jump' function.

Comment: The method of *drawing a picture* (of the graph of $X$) illustrated at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138763 makes short work of this problem.